# List of D3,DC and Crossfilter supported browsers

Tags: html, asp.net, d3.js, crossfilter

I'm working in DC with Crossfilter,
Currently by data visualization is working fine in google chrome, but its not opening in Internet explorer 8 and 10. so, if i have the list of supported browsers it would be useful for me to test for compatibility issues
please advice me on this.

Answer (score 0):

dc.js looks like it's tested on IE10. I don't think it will work on IE8 due to lack of SVG support.